# Is there a predictable replacement for os.urandom using Python's random module?

Tags: python-3.x, random

I'm looking to get *n* random bytes as a bytearray or bytes, as `os.urandom` does.

However I need to be able to set a random seed so the value is reproducable.

```
def urandom_from_random(rng, length):
    return bytes([rng.randint(0, 255) for i in range(length)])

import random
rng = random.Random(42)
data = urandom_from_random(rng, 120)
print(data)
```

The script above works, but isn't very efficient.

Is there a more direct way to do this besides creating many ints and converting them to bytes?

---

Note:

- Making urandom return predictable results is [possible on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053875/bypass-dev-urandomrandom-for-testing), but needs root access.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest function in `random` to what you want is `getrandbits`. It returns an integer with the requested number of bits. If you want to turn that into a `bytes` instance, you can use `int.to_bytes`.

Here's a quick function that pairs those two together:

```
def urandom_from_random(rng, length):
    if length == 0:
        return b''
    integer = rng.getrandbits(length * 8)
    result = integer.to_bytes(length, sys.byteorder)
    return result
```

The byte order you specify to `to_bytes` shouldn't matter. I tell it to use the system's native byte order, but I don't actually know if that makes it any faster than it would be otherwise.

Comment: `random.getrandbits()` uses "little endian" internally to combine 32-bit words generated by the Mersenne Twister algorithm (MT19937). I don't know whether it has any effect on anything

Comment: This is limited by the maximum size of an int, with large values it raises an exception `OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum`.

Comment: How many bytes do you need to request to get that exception? Python's `int` type is variably sized, so it should just work regardless of the sizes involved. I tested with `length` values up to ten thousand with no issues. Are you running my actual code, or some variation? Are you sure you haven't introduced any errors? The exception you mention is what `int.to_bytes` will raise if you give it a too-short byte length for the `int` value you've called it on.

Comment: Values above 2147483648 fail `random.getrandbits()` (CPython 3.5.x)

Comment: Do you *really* need the function to be able to give you two gigabytes of random data in a single call?

Comment: @Blckknght, thats 2147483648 bits, actual limit is 256mb

Comment: @ideasman42: Is that on a 32 or 64 bit version of CPython? Usually, sizes are handled with a signed `size_t`, so the limit would be much higher on a 64 bit build.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 64bit Python. The int isn't representing the range, its storing the actual data.

Comment: @ideasman42: Python 3's `int` is implemented as an array of "digits" (each digit holding 15 bits on 32 bit, or 30 on 64 bit), with the size of the array being represented by an `ssize_t` (the sign of the `ssize_t` says whether the number is positive or negative). On 64 bits, it's perfectly capable of representing a number larger than `2**31-1` bits long (`x = (1 << (1 << 35))` works fine on my Python x64 3.5 on Windows, it just uses 4.3 GB of RAM). The limitation looks to be in `random.getrandbits`, which converts the bit count to a C `long`, on Windows, 32 or 64 bit, a `long` is only 32 bits.

Comment: But on most non-Windows 64 bit systems, a `long` is 64 bits, so you could generate a truly huge amount of random if you had the time to wait for the Mersenne Twister to generate it all (it generates 256 MB surprisingly quickly though, so if you've got the RAM, it could probably fill it quickly enough).

Comment: In this case, the issue is how the C code for `getrandbits` handles the size argument. It parses the number of bits into an ordinary C `int`, which on my 64-bit system is still just 32 bits. I've just tested out a patch for the implementation that makes it use a `ssigned_t` type instead, and that does indeed allow much larger values. Indeed, it allows values much larger than I have memory to actually handle (so I get `MemoryError`s instead of `OverflowError`s for some values).

Comment: I've reported this as a (minor) bug to the Python core developers: http://bugs.python.org/issue27072 Since it's probably an issue only for Windows 64-bit builds (where `int` and `size_t` have different sizes), and only when requesting a really silly amount of random data, I'm not sure how high a priority it will be.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of @Blckknght's answer that takes into account the internal `INT_MAX` limit in `getrandbits`.

```
def urandom_from_random(rng, length):
    if length == 0:
        return b''

    import sys
    chunk_size = 65535
    chunks = []
    while length >= chunk_size:
        chunks.append(rng.getrandbits(
                chunk_size * 8).to_bytes(chunk_size, sys.byteorder))
        length -= chunk_size
    if length:
        chunks.append(rng.getrandbits(
                length * 8).to_bytes(length, sys.byteorder))
    result = b''.join(chunks)
    return result
```

Example use:

```
import random 
rng = random.Random(42)
print(len(urandom_from_random(rng, 300000000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the seed in the begining of your code :

```
import random
random.seed(7)
rng = random.Random(42)
data = urandom_from_random(rng, 120)
```

As long as you use 7 in the seed you have the same random pick. Then you can change it to any value.

Comment: `random.seed(7)` isn't needed. The script works predictably as-is, clarified my question.